# Bash shell complains of invalid options I didn't use ... only on *.mp4 file extensions

Tags: linux, bash, shell, arguments

I have a bunch of MP4 files that look like this:

```
-rw-rw-r-- 1 116M Apr 19 06:08 lULIqx9Akn4.mp4
```

These are youtube videos.  When I try to do anything with all of them, I get a weird error.  Every command I try says that I'm using invalid options (that I am not using).  Here are some examples.

```
$ ls *.mp4
/bin/ls: invalid option -- '7'
Try '/bin/ls --help' for more information.
$ mv *.mp4 videos/
mv: invalid option -- 'L'
Try 'mv --help' for more information.
$ cp *.mp4 videos/.
cp: invalid option -- '7'
Try 'cp --help' for more information.
```

It doesn't do the same thing with a different extension (*.mp3, *.txt, *.sh).

What's going on?  How do I fix this?

I used this as a cheap workaround,

```
find . -name "*.mp4" -exec mv {} videos/. \;
```

but I want to understand what's happening, not just get the job done.

Comment: Do you have some weird alias set?

Comment: My guess would be some weird filenames causing trouble

Comment: @MarcB This actually is a programming question.  I was doing it in bash so I can automate some tasks.  The script itself is exterior to this issue.  Also, your snide tone is quite inappropriate, especially since you are wrong.  Further, the correct answer had to do with how those functions (mv, cp, ls) take arguments, which is unambiguously an issue of programming.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

One of your filenames starts with a hyphen, e.g,. `-7` or `-L`.  Try `ls -- *.mp4` or `cp -- *.mp4 videos`.  Also, allow me to suggest [UNIX and Linux Stack Exchange](https://unix.stackexchange.com) for shell questions :) .

Comment: @Barmar Ah, thank you. I'll delete my previous comment.

Comment: This was it.  Also, I didn't know about the UNIX and Linux Stack Exchange; thanks!

Comment: +1. Note that for many purposes, you can also prevent this by writing `./*.mp4` (since e.g. `./-7L.mp4` doesn't start with `-`).

Answer (score 1):

## Solution:

Either move the files,

```
mv -- *.mp4 ./videos
```

or rename the files in situ...

```
for file in -*.mp4; do mv -- "$file" "${file:1}"; done
```

## Explanation:

My sense is you have a file with a leading `-` in the directly... most commands stop you creating such files but if you copy them from another operating system it can occur. Thus, you need to rename any files with a leading `-` in their filename...

Let me explain with an example...

Let's try to create a file with a leading `-`:

```
touch "-7ULIqx9Akn4.mp4"
touch: illegal option -- 7
```

we can get around this as follows:

```
>touch -- "-7ULIqx9Akn4.mp4"
> ls -al -- -*.mp4
total 0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 13:02 -7ULIqx9Akn4.mp4
```

ok, now lets set up an example and demonstrate a solution...

```
> ls -la
total 0
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 12:49 -75438752.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 12:49 -85438750.mp4
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 n  staff  238 Apr 29 12:49 .
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 n  staff  204 Apr 29 11:18 ..
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 12:36 75438750.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 12:33 7ULIqx9Akn4.mp4
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 n  staff    0 Apr 29 11:19 lULIqx9Akn4.mp4
```

next:

```
ls -- -*.mp4
-75438752.mp4 -85438750.mp4
```

ok, lets now rename these files...

A little explanation here, the following command uses `mv` to remove the leading character. i.e. Find files with a leading `-` and remove the leading character `{$file:1}` from the filename...

```
for file in -*.mp4; do mv -- "$file" "${file:1}"; done
```

Result:

```
> for file in -*.mp4; do mv -- "$file" "${file:1}"; done
> ll
total 0
drwxr-xr-x@ 7 n  238 Apr 29 12:52 ./
drwxr-xr-x@ 6 n  204 Apr 29 11:18 ../
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n    0 Apr 29 12:36 75438750.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n    0 Apr 29 12:49 75438752.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n    0 Apr 29 12:33 7ULIqx9Akn4.mp4
-rw-r--r--@ 1 n    0 Apr 29 12:49 85438750.mp4
-rw-rw-r--@ 1 n    0 Apr 29 11:19 lULIqx9Akn4.mp4
```

## Note

The above does not account for duplicate file names...

Comment: If you're not going to show how to solve the problem, this should just be a comment, not an answer.

Comment: @Barmar - Thankyou, you are correct. I updated to provide an answer.

Comment: You should *always* use `mv -i` for bulk renames like this, in case of duplicate filenames.